# creating loop over the lines of text files

Tags: scripts

i is an integer (lets say 4).
I have three text files (a,b,c) contain single lines with strings, total number of lines of files equal to i (4). For example "a" file contains;

```
trm320
abc000
dfg1002
der5205
```

I need to create the output (on the screen or in the text file) with loop like;

a(1) b(1) c(1) (first line of a,b,c files)

---

a(4) b(4) c(4) (last line of a,b,c files)

What kind of loop do I need to create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste` does exactly what you want.

```
DESCRIPTION
       Write  lines  consisting  of  the sequentially corresponding lines from
       each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.   With  no  FILE,  or
       when FILE is -, read standard input.

       Mandatory  arguments  to  long  options are mandatory for short options
       too.

       -d, --delimiters=LIST
              reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs
```

In your case

```
paste -d " " a b c
```

will do the trick. If you need the output in a file, redirect `>output` the output.

---

To access the `n-th` line of a file, use `sed`. For convenience wrap it up in a Bash function (`pl` is supposed to mean Print Line)

```
function pl {
  sed -n "$1p" $2
}
```

Calling for example `pl 5 a` will print the fifth line of file `a`. To store it in a variable

```
fifth=$(pl 5 a)
```

or combine both tasks

```
paste a b c | pl 5 -
```

to print the fifth line of the concatenated file.

---

To get a file into an array, use `mapfile`, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash):

```
mapfile -t myArray < output.txt
```

Comment: +1 much better than any written bash script. Useful utility!

Comment: I also need to define variable. For example when I type $a[1] I want to see first line. Is there any way to define these variables like that?

Comment: @Tim Why invent the wheel anew every time, right?. The GNU toolbox holds a plethora of those useful helpers.

Comment: for example; sentence="this is a story"
stringarray=($sentence)
echo ${stringarray[0]}; I need to define the lines of text files with this way

Comment: @deepblue_86 it's helpful to tell us that at the beginning. You could then cat them and add each line of file to an array

Comment: @deepblue_86 I would define a bash function using `sed`; see the addendum.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the edit! Very useful and certainly the best way to read a file into an array.